# WP7.1 project not working properly on WP8 device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am working on VOIP app and build the sip library for Windows Phone 7.1 OS. IT is working fine when i run the project on any Windows 7.5 devices. But when i try to run the same project on WP8 device it not working well. It start giving me various exceptions like Null Pontere Refernce Exception in System.Windows.ni.dll . My understanding was if anything which is running fine in WIndows 7.5 device will work fine in Windows 8 device. Can anyone help what will be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MSDN page that could interest you: [App platform compatibility for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

> **In general**, the Windows Phone app platform enables apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1 to run without modification or
>   recompilation on Windows Phone 8.
>   [...]
>   There are other scenarios in which a Windows Phone OS 7.1 app **may
>   behave differently** when it runs on Windows Phone 8.